# Schur-Weyl duality in positive characteristic

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\Rep{Rep}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\SW{SW}$Let $S_k$ be the symmetric group. Let $F$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $\Rep(S_k)$ be the category of representations of $S_k$ over $F$.
Let $\Rep(\GL_n(F))$ be the category of algebraic representations of $\GL_n(F)$.
We can construct a functor $\SW$ from $\Rep(S_k)$ to $\Rep(\GL_n(F))$, $\SW(\sigma)=(\otimes^k F^n\otimes \sigma)^{S_k}$, where $\sigma\in \Rep(S_k)  $.

When $F$ is of characteristic 0, and n>k, it is well-known $\SW$ is a fully faithful and exact functor. Usually it is called Schur-Weyl duality.
My question is:

- When $F$ is of characteristic $p$, is
  $\SW$ still a fully faithful and exact
  functor?

When $p>k$, the representation theory of $S_k$ over $F$ behaves exactly the same as characteristic 0 case, but for algebraic representation of $\GL_n(F)$, it is totally different from characteristic 0 case.

When $p<=k$, representation of $S_k$ is complicated.
It is well-known problem, to determine the decomposition number in $\Rep(S_k)$.

- Is it possible to use Schur-Weyl
  duality to determine the decomposition number for $S_k$?

Since for modular representation theory of reductive group, the similar problem is known or almost known by Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomial.

TO sum up, I would like to ask:

- For my purpose, what is the correct formulation for
  Schur-Weyl duality in positive
  characteristic?

Comment: The keyword is "Schur algebra" (see the work of Green, Dipper, James, Donkin and a book by Martin).

Comment: To second Victor's comment, Schur (and then $q$-Schur) algebras grow out of Schur-Weyl duality in char $p$; this allows one in particular to use finite dimensional algebra techniques for the study of modular representations of general linear groups. Donkin's papers and books are an important source, but by now the literature is large. For instance there is an added chapter on "Truncated Categories and Schur Algebras" in the 2003 AMS second edition of Jantzen's Representations of Algebraic Groups.


Comment: This (modular Schur-Weyl duality) is the topic of Carl Mautner's beautiful 2010 PhD thesis. He obtains the Schur functor geometrically from a geometric relation between the affine Grassmannian for GL_n (where reps of GL_n sit, by the Geometric Satake theorem) and the nilpotent cone for gl_n (where reps of S_n sit, by Springer theory), recovering in particular the modular Schur-Weyl duality theorem of Carter and Lusztig (which ought to be mentioned here independently). 

Comment: As David indicates, Schur-Weyl duality in characteristic `$p$` continues to attract creative interest.   Following his suggestion, the MathSciNet reference to the paper by Carter-Lusztig is  MR0354887 (50 #7364) 20G05 (20C20)  Carter, Roger W.; Lusztig, George, On the modular representations of the general linear and symmetric groups. Math. Z. 136 (1974), 193–242.  (One of two substantial papers they wrote during Lusztig's short time at Warwick.)  .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The questions here have certainly been explored (though not definitively) in many recent papers or preprints on arXiv.    Look for example at the arXiv paper by Stephen Doty [Link](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610591), as well as many others by Steve and/or his collaborators.   Most of the arXiv papers have subject listing RT (some also consider quantum analogues under QA).  But some predate arXiv; there has been a lot of study of decomposition numbers of symmetric groups in prime characteristic, for example, using what little is known about modular representations of GL$_n$.   Not having gone far with this literature myself, I'd suggest that you start the inquiry with available papers and then maybe raise narrower questions here.

My main point at first has been that a lot of literature exists from the past couple of decades, so the questions should focus on what is in that literature (not just Doty's short conference paper I cited).   Concerning the status of modular representations for finite groups of Lie type, what's known is not yet good enough to answer most questions about symmetric groups for small primes.   While Lusztig's conjectures promise a good conceptual picture for primes at least the Coxeter number of the Weyl group, even that much can be implemented only in recursive style.   For small primes little is known, but it would have immediate applications to $S_n$. In classical Schur-Weyl duality the dictionary goes the opposite way.

Comment: Before I posted my questions, I have looked at the paper by Stephen Doty roughly. It seems it doesn't give the answer for what I want immediately.  

Comment: See my edited answer for more details.   But the subject is spread out, so "immediate" answers may be scarce at this point.

Comment: It seems we also have functor from modular representation of $S_k$ to modular representation of finite group of Lie type(representation of $G(k)$  over $\bar{k}$  , where $k$  is a finite field), but isn't it more natural to use representation of Frobenius kernel or hyperalgebra? There are supposed to be some relations with these two different type of representations?

Comment: I tried to give a short answer to the summary question:  *For my purpose, what is the correct formulation for schur-Weyl duality in positive characteristic?*   But to get into the current state of modular representations of general linear or other reductive groups requires the machinery developed in Jantzen's book mentioned above along with related papers.   Restricting to finite subgroups or to Frobenius kernels is a major theme but goes far beyond the study of Schur-Weyl duality in char `$p$`.   (For finite groups, there is also a lot of work on other primes dividing the group order.)

Comment: @Jim, May I ask a question here? Over positive characteristic, Given reductive group $G$, is $\mathcal{O}(G)$  still isomorphic to $\oplus V_\lambda\otimes V_\lambda ^*$ as $G\times G$  representatioin? Here $V_\lambda $ is Weyl module or dual Weyl module. Another question is, On space $\otimes ^k F^n$ , we have action of $GL_n\times S_k$ , if $k<n$ , can we alway decompose $\otimes^k F^n$   as $\oplus V_\lambda \otimes \sigma_\lambda $, where $V_\lambda $ is Weyl module, and $\sigma_\lambda$ is the Specht module. Thank you very much. 

Comment: @xiyu: For the first question, you have to settle for a *good filtration* rather than a direct sum decomposition as found in char 0.  In such a filtration, the subquotients look like `$H^0(\lambda) \otimes H^0(\lambda^*)$` (tensor product of dual Weyl modules) where `$\lambda^* = -w_0 \lambda$` is the "dual" weight.   This was proved in different ways by M. Koppinen, J. LMS 30 (1984) and then S. Donkin, J. Algebra 113 (1988); see Jantzen's book, II.4.20.  For the second question, I'd start with the 1974 paper by Carter-Lusztig.  But at the moment I don't recall what's been done later.

Comment: (Continued comment)  Again for the individual tensor powers of the natural `$n$`-dim module, you can't expect to get a direct sum but only a good filtration as `$GL_n$`-module.   Good filtrations (or their dual versions using Weyl modules) are the best substitute for complete reducibility in prime characteristic.   Fortunately these filtrations behave well under tensoring since dual Weyl modules do.   Similarly, Specht modules for `$S_k$` usually aren't direct sums of simple modules.   In some ways, the symmetric group and general linear group theories are parallel. 

Comment: Thanks.
Is there any generalization of symmetric $(GL_n,GL_m)$-duality to positive characteristic? Over characteristic 0, one can find it in Howe's paper "$(GL_n,GL_m)-duality and symmetric plethysm$".
I tried to look for some related literature, but I haven't found anything except the generalization of skew Howe duality in positive characteristic.

Comment: Donkin's first work on tilting modules did lead to some papers on Howe duality;  see for example:
MR1390747 (98f:20026) 
Adamovich, A. M.; Rybnikov, G. L,.
Tilting modules for classical groups and Howe duality in positive characteristic. 
Transform. Groups 1 (1996), no. 1-2, 1--34, and later MR1801579 (2002g:20079) 
McNinch, George J.,
Filtrations and positive characteristic Howe duality.
Math. Z. 235 (2000), no. 4, 651–685.


Comment: It seems in these two papers, they considered action of $GL(V)\times GL(W)$ on skew symmetric power $\Lambda (V\otimes W)$. My question is about action of $GL(V)\times GL(W)$ on the symmetric power $S(V\otimes W)$, like the situation in Howe's paper. 

Comment: This might best be formulated as a separate question, which George McNinch would be able to comment on better than I can.

Answer (score 1):

(This seems to be an old question, but just recently edited, so it came up today.)

The condition that $n \geq k$ means that the polynomial representations of degree $k$ in the algebraic representations of $GL_n(\mathbb F)$ agree with the category $\mathcal P^k(\mathbb F)$ of `strict polynomial functors of degree $k$' as described by Suslin and Friedlander in the mid 1990's.  It is useful to view these categories, for all $k$, as a single object, and one can also very usefully work over any field (e.g. finite fields), not just algebraically closed ones.

The functor you wrote down is right adjoint to an exact functor $e_k: \mathcal P^k(\mathbb F) \rightarrow Rep_{\mathbb F}(S_k)$.  $e_k$ also has a left adjoint, and one is in the `recollement' setting.

In the finite field setting, I filter in the `kernel' of $e_k$ in my study of filtrations of these sorts of functor categories in [A stratification of generic representation theory and generalized Schur algebras, K-theory 26 (2002), 15-48].  This paper will also give you many references to relevent functor category literature.